# C++/CMake/azure DevOps code coverage and unit testing

Tags: c++, docker, azure-pipelines, code-coverage, googletest

I’m developing few modules for my IoT project in C++, and CMake.
Finally, The module is built into a docker image, and pulled to the device, using azure IoT platform.
Also, i have a azure devops CI/CD pipeline to automate the deployment.

Now, i came across unit testing and codec overage.
I used gtest to do unit testing, and lcov to calculate code coverage,locally

But i want this to integrate with my pipeline.

Can someone suggest a best methode,or any alternative to do this.

Answer (score 3):

In Azure Devops, there is no out-of-the-box task to perform google test.

You need to use the Command Line task to run the command to running the test.

Here is my example:

```
steps:
- script: |
   cmake -S. -Bbuild 
   cmake --build build
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'

- script: |
   cd build
   ctest
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

Then the project will build and run the unit test.

[image]

To use lcov to calculate code coverage, you need to make sure the lcov has been installed in your build agent.

If you are using the [Microsoft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), you need to run the command to install the lcov tool first.

Here is the example: run on Linux Ubuntu agent:

```
- script: 'sudo apt-get install lcov'
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'

- script: |
   lcov --directory ./build/ --capture --output-file ./code_coverage.info -rc lcov_branch_coverage=1
   
   genhtml code_coverage.info --branch-coverage --output-directory ./code_coverage_report/
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

Then it will generate the HTML Test report and you could see the code coverage in the task log.

[image]

On the other hand, based on your description, the required tools have been installed in your local environment.

I suggest that you could directly use the [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install).

In this case, you can directly migrate your local operation steps directly to azure pipeline.

Comment: The problem is, I’m building my code inside a docker image. So I’m confused how can i take out the lcov final html file out of the docker image.

Comment: Hi @Jff.  Can you share the task you used to build and test your code?